# Deutsche Adjektive für "high-level"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, meaning-in-context, single-word-request

In a lot of situations, the English adjective "high-level" can be translated by "hochrangig", when it implies something out of the ordinary. But "high-level" is also very often used with the sense of "simplified" or "partial".

For instance this dialogue:
Q: Have you fully audited the accounting data ?
A: Not yet, so far I have only performed a high-level review.

What would be the corresponding German adjective for this usage of "high-level" ?

Comment: If you "high-level" should mean something like "not very detailed" you could use e.g. "überblicksmäßig" or "grob". BTW: Is the word "controlled" correct in the English sentence? I would use "checked" instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your definition of "high-level" meaning "simplified"; it's not listed in Wiktionary. But I think I see what you're getting at. You can talk about a 'high-level" computer language, which  hides details of implementation from the programmer, but Python is not a simplified version of assembly language.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @ Bodo:yes, the verb "checked" or "audited" would be better in the English sentence. And thanks for your suggestion with "überblicksmäßig". @ RDBury: yes "high-level" in this sense may not be in Wiktionary, but I can assure you it is very commonly used in this sense in private companies, be it in the UK or in Continental Europe. I basically hear it every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in German translating the adjective is possible (see  answer by a_donda, e.g. *oberflächlich* or *flüchtig*), more likely a properly modified verb is used instead or in addition, as

- durchgeblättert
- überflogen
- quergelesen

(I don't like the word, but I also hear *durchgescrollt*, i. e. quickly press page down until end of document is reached, which of course applies to electronic documents only; I would always prefer *durchgeblättert*.)

Comment: "Durchgesehen" may also work if "durchgeblättert" sounds too papery.

Comment: Thank you @guidot and HalvarF for your answers !

Answer (score 3):

Suggested translation for "[...] so far I have only performed a high-level review":

> Bislang habe ich mir lediglich einen kursorischen Überblick verschafft.

> Bis jetzt hab' ich die Daten nur quer gelesen.

> Ich habe mir die Daten nur oberflächlich angesehen.

> Ich bin die Daten bisher nur flüchtig durchgegangen.

... and possibly others.

Comment: I have to admit I've never read "kursorisch" before. It seems to be a literal equivalent of English "cursory". Duden lists it as rare and "bildungssprachlich": [kursorisch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kursorisch).

Comment: @Hulk yep, seems it is the same, including the formal use. Common root in Latin.

Comment: Thank you @a_donda and Hulk for your answers and proposals !

Comment: To 'counterbalance' the first comment, I will just say that I use *kursorisch* from time to time and also enocunter it rather frequently. By the way, duden.de doesn't say it's "rare", if I'm reading this correctly, just "bildungssprachlich" (that's certainly true) -- to provide some perspective, a corpurs search returns 302 matches for "kursorisch*" in the Süddeutsche Zeitung (daily) newspaper between 1992 and 2020, suggesting they use it about 11 times a year. That's not too bad. #teamkursorisch ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One more suggestion:

> Bis jetzt konnte ich nur eine Plausibilitätsprüfung machen.

A variant with a Denglish ingredient would be

> Bis jetzt konnte ich nur einen Plausibilitätscheck machen.

Comment: Danke @Frost für deinen Vorschlag!